# Adding UIBezierPath to CAShapeLayer in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am trying to add a bezierPath as a sublayer of a view.

Following is my code

```
let arrPoints = Array(picture.points)

let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()

bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: (arrPoints.first?.x.cgFloat()!)! * scaleX,
                            y: (arrPoints.first?.y.cgFloat()!)! * scaleY))

for index in 1...(arrPoints.count - 1) {
    let point = arrPoints[index]
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x.cgFloat()! * scaleX,
                                   y: point.y.cgFloat()! * scaleY))
}

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(hexString: picture.color)!.cgColor
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = picture.brushSize.cgFloat()!

let viewSymbol = SVGImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))
viewSymbol.accessibilityHint = "Brush"
viewSymbol.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
viewSymbol.alpha = picture.alpha.cgFloat()!
viewSymbol.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
viewSymbol.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#dfdfdf", transparency: 0.25)

viewLayerActive!.addSubview(viewSymbol)

let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
viewSymbol.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

Also, the attached image shows the result of my current implementation where the blue outlined box to the right is the sublayer and the LightGray box over `Szpilman` is the view to which I’m adding the sublayer

[image]

How can I add the sublayer exactly into the gray box?

Comment: just check what arrPoints ocntain. It should start from 0,0 and end there. I guess it might be because of the frame reference. If its not that you might have to subtract origin.x and origin.y from each point.

Comment: @MohammadSadiq you're solution worked. Thanks a ton!!!